# Color picker with only 1 slider

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a color picker that uses only one slider. I know this won't allow for all colors and I won't be able to adjust alpha, hue and saturation. There are many examples of color pickers out there. One common color picker involves using a square and a linear spectrum. The square allowing you to change hue and saturation. I just want the linear spectrum values. I would love to do this with some algorithms but I can't think of how to start it. Worst case, I could use an array that has the colors and just use the progress bar's value as the index.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following code that matches what I wanted to do pretty well. It could be modified to provide a larger range of values. The Code is pretty rough but I think you get the idea.

```
public int getColorFromProgress(int progress)
{
    int color1 = 0, color2 = 0, color = 0;
    float p = (float)progress;
    if(progress <= 10) /* black to red */
    {
        color1 = 0;
        color2 = 0xff0000;  
        p = progress / 10.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 25) /* red to yellow */
    {
        color1 = 0xff0000;
        color2 = 0xffff00;  
        p = (progress - 10) / 15.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 40) /* yellow to lime green */
    {
        color1 = 0xffff00;
        color2 = 0x00ff00;  
        p = (progress - 25) / 15.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 55) /* lime green to aqua */
    {
        color1 = 0x00ff00;
        color2 = 0x00ffff;  
        p = (progress - 40) / 15.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 70) /* aqua to blue */
    {
        color1 = 0x00ffff;
        color2 = 0x0000ff;  
        p = (progress - 55) / 15.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 90) /* blue to fuchsia */
    {
        color1 = 0x0000ff;
        color2 = 0x00ff00;  
        p = (progress - 70) / 20.0f;
    }
    else if(progress <= 98) /* fuchsia to white */
    {
        color1 = 0x00ff00;
        color2 = 0xff00ff;  
        p = (progress - 90) / 8.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        color1 = 0xffffff;
        color2 = 0xffffff;
        p = 1.0f;
    }

    int r1 = (color1 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int r2 = (color2 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g1 = (color1 >> 8) & 0xff;
    int g2 = (color2 >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b1 = (color1) & 0xff;
    int b2 = (color2) & 0xff;

    int r3 = (int) ((r2 * p) + (r1 * (1.0f-p)));
    int g3 = (int) (g2 * p + g1 * (1.0f-p));
    int b3 = (int) (b2 * p + b1 * (1.0f-p));

    color = r3 << 16 | g3 << 8 | b3;

    return color;
}
```